# How can I remove selected text highlight after unfocus?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

here is the code:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.focusedChild!.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SelectableText("Hello, World!"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to unfocus SelectableText but the selected text highlight still showing.

Comment: Yeasin Sheikh, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this workaround,

It will change the key of the SelectableText widget removing the current highlighted text.

```
  var _index = 0;
  Key _getKey() => Key('selectableKey$_index');
  void _removeSelection() => setState(() => _index++);

     @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              home: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  _removeSelection();
                },
                child: const Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: SelectableText(key: _getKey(),"Hello, World!"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```